# Jackson module with @JsonProperty defaultValue handling

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am using spring boot with jackson to create a rest api. I know that `@JsonProperty` annotation has `defaultValue` field. 
In
 it's javadoc its said:

> textual default value defined as metadata. NOTE: **core databind does NOT make any use of this value;** it is currently only exposed to extension modules.

So I found some modules for jackson on maven central repository, however I couldn't find anyware information about which extension I should use to enable defaultValue handling.

Is there such module?

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentations of [JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#defaultValue()) , the defaultValue property **may be used to *document* expected default value.** They have added this property in version 2.5. And as per their view

> It is possible that in future this annotation could be used for value defaulting, and especially for default values of Creator properties,since they support {@link #required()} in 2.6 and above.

As of now till version 2.8 we are not able to use this annotation to set default value. Here we may rely on Java to have default values for member variables.

Comment: I don't want to use default values for member varibales because I want object to be immutable so I have only constructor and getters. I understand that code jackson library doesn't make use of this property, hovewer there are some number of extensions which can use it. The question was does they, and if there is such extension please can you give it name or link to it.

Comment: It's tricky, I know you can't achieve immutability with default values. However you may have constructor in java code which checks if value has not given to copy constructor to set; if not, place/put your default value, provided that you have lesser fields to have default values.

Meantime I have been looking jsckson-annotation2.8.7 to validate if it has leveraged defaultValue & definitely expect reply from my side.

Comment: Jackson-annotations has added this property only for documentation from version 2.5. I checked 2.8.7 doc, it says same.